# Setup Second Netgear Device as Access Point

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router, wireless-access-point

I bought a second netgear router to use as a Repeater or Access Point. I've never done this and its giving me a ton of trouble.

Of course, routerlogin.net doesn't work because that goes to my primary router! This doesn't work for multiple Netgear devices on a single network, so I'm curious about how to get around that.

When looking at my primary device (Netgear R7000), I can see the additional device in the device list:

[image: Device shown in R7000]

Going to this IP directly doesn't do anything - See screenshot:

[image: timeout]

Also I read online to use an IP scanner.. this shows that this IP address can't be connected to with Angry IP Scanner.

[image: angry ip scanner]

**What else I've tried:**

- factory resetting the R6700 router.
- connecting this new R6700 to the current router via its WAN port, and a typical LAN port.. same IP - nothing.
- Connecting the R6700 directly to a windows computer with a LAN cable.. this works but then I turned on AP mode and could no longer access the setup page.

Is it supposed to be this hard? Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: you might want to try http instead of https

Comment: no go - same issue